# What is the connection between Haman and HaMelech?

Tags: megillat-esther, gematria-numerology, haman

Do any Meforshim explain a connection between the equivalent gemtriya of "Haman" and "HaMelech" (95) repeated throughout Megillas Esther?

Answer (score 1):

I once heard.....That this shows the continuous war between G-d and haman/amalek.The story reads as if haman got angry at.....then he blew up.Yet the genuine underlying cause was a everlasting hate of G-d and his children (jews)                                             This is also why there is hidden names of G-d when the time came to hang him.This is explained as if to say “He’s my enemy “ (please step aside)